# Structuring Coffeescript and using the @ keyword

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, this, project-structuring

This is probably very basic stuff but I'm stuck and a bit clueless.

I wrote a Snake game recently in CoffeeScript, but I'm not at all happy with the way I [structured the code](https://github.com/cabaret/canvas_coffee_snake/blob/master/coffee/snake.coffee).

I'm trying to rewrite this using classes. I have a Game class, a Snake class, a Food class. It makes sense in my head to do it this way. However, to access variables and functions, I'm using the '@' (this) keyword, and I feel like I'm completely overdoing it. For example, I have a list of constants at the top of my Game class. I had to declare all of them as `@CONSTANT` to be able to access them. Or, inside of a method:

```
clearCanvas: ->
    @ctx.clearRect 0, 0, @canvas.width, @canvas.height
```

The same goes for method calls. For example:

```
init: ->
    window.snake = new Snake()
    @showStartScreen()
```

Can someone tell me if this is okay to do, or how I should structure my code? I can put a link up to the code I'm working with at the moment, if someone would be so kind to review it for me. (Edit: actually [here it is](https://raw.github.com/cabaret/SnakeRewritten/master/coffee/snake.coffee))

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using CoffeeScript classes you'll be making heavy use of `@`. Any properties on your objects must be accessed through `@` or `this`. Here's how you should be using constants:

```
class Game
  up:     1
  right:  2
  down:   4
  left:   8

  someMethod: ->
    console.log @up, @right, @down, @left

console.log "Class accessible #{Game::up}"

g = new Game
console.log "Object accessinble #{g.up}"

g.someMethod()
```

Also, @thejh is right. You should be using soft tabs at 2 space width.

Comment: I put up a link to the full code. Thanks for clearing up that I'll be making heavy use of @. Are there alternatives to this or is this an okay way to work?

Comment: Ah, thanks. Declaring them with '@' in front of them didn't actually make a lot of sense, dit it now? I removed those; code still seems to work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the tabs (you should use spaces instead), it looks fine to me. Oh, and the semicolon in the last line shouldn't be there. :)

Comment: Oh. Missed out on the semicolon, and apparently I had soft tabs off in TextMate for some reason. Thanks for pointing that out ;)